# How can I create a modal dialog with a text and a listbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, dialog, modal-dialog

Since I am new in javascript my question is how can I create a modal dialog using javascript. In this modal dialog I want to have 3 controls. An editbox, a textbox and a listbox. The user enters value in the edit box and if there are more than one result i want to display it in the listbox. Then the user selects one from the listbox and pressing the OK button the dialog returns the selected value.

I 've been trying to find a sample code to do this with no luck. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a javascript library like dhtmlx (or jQuery, I haven't tried that).

http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxWindows/index.shtml

With dhtmls you can define custom modal windows by javascript!